# Kentico - Menu redirects work intermittently

Tags: kentico

I have a dropdown menu and use Hierarchical viewers to transform/display it. On the dropdown, I have a couple of redirects (one to external site and one to an internal page), but the redirects don't always work - sometimes, they worked this hour but the next one they didn't, and now they don't work at all. The links just take me to the kentico pages, but not the destination pages.
It sounds strange but it's happened and I don't really know why. Hope someone would help!

Is it by any chance because of my transformation for the menu?

```
Level 0:
<li class="{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuClass) %}">
<a href="{% GetDocumentUrl()%}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption)%}</a>
 {^SubLevelPlaceHolder^}
</li>

Level 1:
<li><a href="{% GetDocumentUrl()%}">{% HTMLEncode(DocumentMenuCaption) %}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple questions
1: Are you logged in when you try?  If you are logged in and not in live mode (which happens a lot), many times it will not render the redirects (because it thinks you want to edit the page).
2: Is there full page or webpart caching on it?  It is possible that it caches a working result then a non if it renders differently for different users.

Try those first!

Comment: Thanks! Let me try. I always log in since it's staging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as a CMS user doing your testing? If you are logged in, it won't always follow the redirect. Look in your browser for a link to "Close preview mode" or test it in a different browser or a private tab where you are definitely logged out of Kentico.